# Installing flask-socketio in cookiecutter-flask

Tags: python, flask, cookiecutter

I opened a command shell and made `pip install flask-socketio` . When I added in `extensions.py`
`from flask_socketio import SocketIO`

I got an error after doing `npm start` :

```
Error: While importing 'autoapp', an ImportError was raised:
[FLASK]
[FLASK] Traceback (most recent call last):
[...]
[FLASK]     from flask_socketio import SocketIO
[FLASK] ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'flask_socketio'
```

I tried to run the virtual environment manually and install the module but I did not managed to do it. I also tried to uninstall and install.

Comment: maybe try `python -m pip install ...`.Maybe you have two Pythons and `pip` may install modules for one Python but you may run other Python. But Pythons don't share modules